# Regex find match within number range

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a series of files with the following naming convention..."2020.01.01 W1 Forecast.xlsm". I am trying to loop through a directory while searching the file title pattern that matches the year 2020 and greater or at least a broader range (i.e. 2020-2030) so I don't have to alter my script every year. I've tried the following but have been unsuccessful in getting the pattern to match anything other than the current year of 2020. The naming convention starts with the year string.

```
path_str = '/Users/X/Desktop/Test_Directory/'

pattern_str = '*2020.*Forecast.xlsm'

p = Path(path_str)
files = p.rglob(pattern_str)

for file in files:
    print(file)
```

sample output:

```
/Users/X/Desktop/Test_Directory/2020.08.03 Week 32 Forecast.xlsm
/Users/X/Desktop/Test_Directory/2020.01.06 Week 2 Forecast.xlsm
/Users/X/Desktop/Test_Directory/2020.06.18 Week 25 Forecast.xlsm
/Users/X/Desktop/Test_Directory/2020.06.22 Week 26 Forecast.xlsm
```

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want to match 2020 but from 2021 - 2030 use `202[1-9]`

Comment: thank you for your comment. I do want to match the current year and any range greater. I tried the first pattern string but it isn't picking up the file I purposely renamed to read "2021.01.01...."

Comment: I think it should match `^202[0-9]\b.*Forecast\.xlsm$` https://regex101.com/r/XqBscA/1 or a larger range `^(?:202[0-9]|20[3-9]\d)\b.*Forecast\.xlsm$` https://regex101.com/r/ZuWYZi/1

Comment: If it does not work, perhaps you can add the code that is not working for you to the question which might make it easier to find the issue.

Comment: pattern_str = '^(20[0-2][0-9]|20[0-3][0-0]).*Forecast.xlsm$'  This will only look for the year and Forecast.xlsm at the end of file name https://regex101.com/r/ZeS9DF/1

Comment: I updated the original post with test code snippet to test if the suggestions work. For some reason only the pattern listed return results. All the others suggested do not especially when using the ^ at the beginning. I noticed this when testing some of my own solutions. There doesn't seem to be a leading space in the naming convention either.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Updated to include test snippet. All the other suggestions don't seem to return results.

Comment: @bbal20 Do you mean like this? `^.*202[0-9]\b.*Forecast\.xlsm$` https://regex101.com/r/yU6OYD/1

Comment: @bbal20 Or a bit more specific `^.*\b202[0-9]\.(?:1[0-2]|0[1-9])\.(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]) Week (?:5[0-3]|[1-4][0-9]|0?[1-9]) Forecast\.xlsm$`  https://regex101.com/r/EkWWpz/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for: `'^20[2-9][0-9].+(\.xlsm)$'`

It says start with 2020 thru 2099, followed by any character `.` one or more times `+`, and end with xlsm `(\.xlsm)$`.  Note the backslash in the last part.  It is required to escape the period, otherwise it will interrupt it as any character.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how far you want to go, but if your goal is only to identify the year in a range from 2020-2030, than this is your regular expresion for you complete path: `^.*20(2\d|30).*$`.

Because your are working with a path, I would suggest that you split your string on the last slash `/` before using the regular expression on the last item of the list. Than you are able to specify your regular expression for the file name.

Maybe this will help:

```
import re
for file in files:
    my_string = file.split('/')[-1]
    match = re.find('^20(2\d|30).*\.xml$', my_string)
    if match:
        print(file)
```

Maybe try yourself with this [tool](https://regex101.com/).

I also want to add some more information about regular expressions, so you can understand what is going on.

1. `^` - This looks for the start of the string. The reason why some answers were not successful so far.
2. `.` - This looks for any symbol. So you can easily overcome some uninteresting parts. But be careful, because of this you have to specify a dot like this `\.`
3. `$` - This means the end of the string.
4. `\d` - this is a synonym for digit and matches `[0-9]`
5. `*` - this is the greedy symbol. This trys to match from zero to as many items as possible of the wanted type. Examples:

   a. `.*` - This try to find as many symbols as possible, no type defines.

   b. `\d*` - This trys to find as many digits as possible.
6. `+` - this is also a greedy symbol but has to match at least once.

Comment: `[2\d|30]` is a character class that match **1** character in the list: `2, digits, pipe, 3, 0`

Comment: Thank you for taking time to provide some direction. I will try it today. It is weird everything that has been suggested should work but files aren't being returned for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your second pattern, you're missing a `.` wildcard after the year, You probably want

`^(202[0-9]|2030).*Forecast\.xlsm`

rather than

`^(202[0-9]|2030)*Forecast.xlsm`

You can use a site like https://regexr.com/ to experiment with regexes.

But you might want to consider fetching the most recent files with programming logic instead of regexes, you could parse the file name and select a date range e.g. using `datetime`.

---

### Update

Starting from your updated code:

```
import datetime
path_str = '/Users/X/Desktop/Test_Directory/'
pattern_str = '*Forecast.xlsm'  # All your report files

p = Path(path_str)
files = p.rglob(pattern_str)

for file in files:
    # # uncomment in case there are different patterns in that folder:
    # if not re.match(r"\d{4}\.\d{2}.\d{2}.*", file.name): continue
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(file.name[:10], "%Y.%m.%d")
    current_year = datetime.datetime.today().year
    if date > datetime.datetime(current_year, 1, 1):
        print(date)
```

This will filter your list of files for names in the current year.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the original post to show the test code and for some reason the only pattern to return results is the fairly simple one listed. I've tried all others including your suggestion and nothing is returned. It is the oddest thing. There doesn't seem to be any leading blanks or spaces in the file naming convention either.

Comment: @bbal20 I read this as there are more files in your directory than your sample output shows? As you're filtering for `*2020.*Forecast.xlsm`, with the wildcard in the beginning there shouldn't be an issue with leading characters. I'd have to guess here, maybe a hidden file extension like `...Forecast.xlsm.xlsm`? Could you list some of the file names in your directory including those that should get have been matched but didn't?

Comment: Sure. So I am just testing on my local file system so I tried to re-create with sample files to ensure I pull in the correct files. variations of files names currently are...'2020.01.01 W1 Forecast.xlsm', '2021.01.01 W1 Forecast.xlsm', '2020.01.01W1 Amortized Rev.xlsm'. I only want the files that read 'Forecast'. I am able to pull in 2020 files but as soon as I try to include all of the suggested methods above I don't get any files returned in my loop. Even when I replace the * at the beginning with ^ then is fails to work. Doesn't make sense to me.